# Union data type in database design

Tags: sql, database-design

I would need to store the following value V in a database. An instance of V is linked with a certain record in a certain table. The problem with V is that it has a resemblance to a [union type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) and can indicate three things:

1. V has an integer value, meaning that the value should be used for the record in question.
2. V is absent, i.e. NULL, meaning that a global setting takes precedence for the record in question.
3. V has a meaning of "ANY", meaning that no value should be used for the record in question.

1 and 2 are easy (make it a NULLable integer column), but how to deal with 3? Now I don't feel comfortable using a special numeric value for indicating the ANY state, because e.g. -1 and 0 are totally valid values for case 1.

What has come to mind so far is

- Putting this union type into a separate table that has two columns, one for the numeric value and one for the ANY condition (boolean), and a nillable foreign key reference to it.
- Storing it as a VARCHAR column and using some special character (e.g. "*") for ANY state.

Is there any "industry standard" way of doing this? :)

For reference, this union type looks something like this in XSD representation:

```
<complexType name="V">
    <choice>
        <element name="anyValue" type="xs:string" fixed="" />
        <element name="numericValue" type="xs:int" />
    </choice>
</complexType>

<complexType name="E">
    <sequence>
        <element ... />
        <element ... />
        <element name="configValue" type="V" minOccurs="0" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it as either.

Nullable foregn key. And in the foregn key table there would be a row that indicates that it has the "any state".. for example has all columns as null.

or addin a int/boolean column to inditake an overiding state.

Please don't use varchar for linking to other tables...

I have seen many solutions to this problem and all of them have serious issues. This is never going to be pretty. And try to tailor your solution for the code that is going to consume this mess. Make it as simple for that as you can. In those situations readability is king.

But best advice is never to get into those situations but that I know is not always wihtin your power

Comment: So apparently there's no silver bullet to this one... I ended up setting up a separate table for hosting this value in order to avoid having some magical varchar column with hidden logic. Accepting this answer as a reward for confirming my assumptions :)